# handling post requests for multiples selects

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have a  multiples select elements, and I submit them with one button. Here is an example :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="inner">
        <form method="POST" action="test"> 
            <label  name="first">first</label>
            <select style="display:inline-block">
            <option value="value1" name ="value1">test 1 </option>
            <option value="value2" name= "value2">test 2</option>

          </select>  
          <label name="second">second</label>
          <select style="display:inline-block">
            <option value="4">1</option>
            <option value="5">2</option>
            <option value="6">3</option>

          <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button" >

          </form>
      </div>




</body>
</html>
```

and I'm trying to handle them using nodejs and express as follows:

```
const express = require('express');
const app  = express()
var path = require('path')
var fs = require('fs')
app.use(express.static('public'))
app.use(express.urlencoded())
console.log(__dirname)

app.get('/',function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/index.html'))
})
app.post('/test', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body.value1)
})

app.listen(2000)
```

apparently it's not correct, so my question is how can I do it?

thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have done mistakes while writing html I think. 
First you have to add name attribute to select boxes, so you can use values on server side.
Secondly you didn't closed second select element.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="inner">
        <form method="POST" action="test"> 
          <label  name="first">first</label>
          <select style="display:inline-block" name='select_box_1'>
            <option value="value1" name ="value1">test 1 </option>
            <option value="value2" name= "value2">test 2</option>

          </select>  
          <label name="second">second</label>
          <select style="display:inline-block" name="select_box_2">
            <option value="4">1</option>
            <option value="5">2</option>
            <option value="6">3</option>
          </select>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button" >

        </form>
      </div>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Murat, thanks for replying and welcome to SO.  did you test your answer, I can't see any change ?

Comment: @Engine look on `select` element there is an attribute `name` which is important if you want to access the value of a selected option on the server.